# Prevent a specific matlab gui pushbutton to change size when display settings are changed in windows

Tags: html, matlab, user-interface, gif

I create a pushbutton to put a gif as my program is loading. The button must have a static size in order to assure that the entire gif fits, but the borders of the button behind does not show. I have tried getting rid of the borders and I have tried using something other than a pushbutton. Nothing seems to work.

Below is an example code of what I have done:

```
pos = [3, 4, 50, 40];
gif = sprintf('<html><img src="file:/%s\\myGif.gif"/></html>',pwd); 
ld = uicontrol('style','push', 'BackgroundColor', 'w', 'ForegroundColor',...
'w', 'pos', pos, 'String',gif,'enable','inactive','CData',uint8(240*ones(18,18,3)));
```

Comment: If you set 'units' of any child of `figure` class to anything but `normalized` it will be bound to the bottom-left corner in absolute measures. So say `set(ld,'units','centimeters')` should do the trick.

Comment: It worked, thank you! Perhaps you can riddle me this: Behind the gif I have an image. I use axes to put the image there. If display settings in windows change, the size of the image changes despite the fact that I use 'Units', 'Normalize' on the axes. Is there any way to make it fixed to the size of the image?

Comment: The problem is that you use `Units`,`Normalized` property for axes. If you use `set(ax_handle,'position',[x,y,w,h],'units','inches')` you will set the `position` in units relative to the figure dimension and then you will set them fixed (the values x,y,w and h will be transformed to inches). If you use `set(ax_handle,'units','inches','position',[x,y,w,h])` you will set the `position` in inches directly.

Answer (score 0):

The figure, axes, uicontrols, etc. have `Units` property which can be set to `inches`, `centimeters`, `points`, `pixels`, `characters` and `normalized`.

For example let's have figure and one push button in it.

```
fig=figure();
pb =uicontrol('style','pushbutton','string','Push','parent',fig);
```

When the `Units` property is set to any value but `normalized`, the values of `position` and `outerposition` properties are bound to bottom-left corner of the parent entity (say `fig` handle is a parent of `pb`) and the length of the unit (say `set(pb,'units','inches')`). In that case when parent(`fig`) is moved and/or resized, the child position will remain same to the bottom-left corner and its size won't be changed (since it is bound to absolute value)

When the `Units` is set to `normalized` (say `set(pb,'units','normalized')`) the `position` and `outerposition` properties are bound to bottom-left corner **and** the size of the parent. In that case when the parent (`fig`) is resized, position of child will remain in same relative position to the parent frame and so does the size of the child (since it is bound to parent dimensions).

This behaviour is independent on the parents `units` property.

If the location of the child - first two elements of `(outer)position` - is wanted to be relative to the parent dimensions but the size of the child - last two elements of `(outer)position` - is wanted to be constant the resolution is less straightforward. Typical case is when controls are on the right side of the figure.

When the user is responsible for the resize one can use `ResizeFcn` property and create routine that will change appropriate properties of the children.

When the code is responsible for the resize one can read the `position` properties before the command possibly leading to the resize action and then re-set those values to fit one's needs.